# Minimize number of shops while reaching all customers

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

In this particular issue, I have an imaginary city divided into squares - basically a *M*x*N* grid of squares covering the city. *M* and *N* can be relatively big, so I have cases with more than 40,000 square cells overall.

I have a number of customers *Z* distributed in this grid, some cells will contain many customers while others will be empty. I would like to find a way to place the minimum number of shops (only one per cell) to be able to serve all customers, with the restriction that all customers must be “in reach” of one shop and all customers need to be included.

Note: I already know which customers can reach which shops.

As an additional couple of twist, I have these constraints/issues:

1. There is a maximum distance that a customer can travel - if the shop is in a cell too far away then the customer cannot be associated with that shop. Edit: it’s not really a distance, it’s a measure of how easy it is for a customer to reach a shop, so I can’t use circles...
2. While respecting the condition (1) above, there may well be multiple shops in reaching distance of the same customer. In this case, the “closest“ shop should win.

At the moment I’m trying to ignore the issue of costs - many customers means bigger shops and larger costs - but maybe at some point I’ll think about that too. The problem is, I have no idea of the name of the problem I’m looking at nor about possible algorithmic solutions for it: can this be solved as a Linear Programming problem?

I normally code in Python, so any suggestions on a possible algorithmic approach and/or some code/libraries to solve it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: as a follow up, I kind of found out I could solve this problem as a MINLP “uncapacitated facility problem”, but all the information I have found are way too complex: I don’t care to know which customer is served by which shop, I only care to know if and where a shop is built. I have a secondary way - as post processing - to associate a customer to the most appropriate shop.

All the codes I found set up this monstrous linear system associating a constraint per customer per shop (as “explained” here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem#Uncapacitated_facility_location), so in a situation like mine I could easily end up with a linear system with millions of rows and columns, which with integer/binary variables will take about the age of the universe to solve.

There must be an easier way to handle this...

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224042/minimize-number-of-shops-while-reaching-all-customers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for the problem of minimizing the number of shops the actual number of  customers in a given cell doesn't matter.  You only need to know whether there is at least one customer in a cell, so you might as well eliminate any duplicate customers that are in the same cell.

You can formulate your problem as a *set covering problem* and solve it via integer linear programming, with one variable per cell and one constraint per customer.  For $i\in \{1,\dots,M\}$ and $j\in \{1,\dots,N\}$, let binary variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether a shop is built at cell $(i,j)$.  For each customer $c$, let $R_c$ be the set of cells that are within reach of that customer.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to the following linear constraints:
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in R_c} x_{i,j}\ge 1 \quad \text{for each customer $c$}$$

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be doing the right thing with the right solver (CBC). lpsolve has been running for hours with no results yet.

Comment: You might consider supplying an initial feasible solution obtained by the following greedy algorithm: at each step, select the location that reaches the most customers that have not yet been covered.

Comment: An even simpler initial feasible solution is to build a shop at every cell that contains a customer.